# Oracle SQL: select from different tables from the result of a variable

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hi,
I need to create a select with a condition for the from clause: if the variable is equal to `POS` the select must be done with table `tb_a` and if the variable is equal to `PRE` the selected will be done with the table `tb_b`.
I tried both ways below, but neither worked. The number of columns in the tables is different.

```sql
SELECT * FROM tb_a WHERE '&prod' = 'POS'
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM tb_b WHERE '&prod' = 'PRE';

SELECT * 
  FROM
 (CASE '&prod'
  WHEN 'prod' = 'POS' THEN tb_a
  WHEN 'prod' = 'PRE' THEN tb_b
  END);
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: Why did your first query fail? Littlefoot's answer should work for you, unless the two tables have different columns. Can you please edit your question and post the entire error message?

Comment: the number of columns in the tables is different

Comment: If the table columns are different, the best answer depends on the precise context of how you're running the SQL. Will you always run this statement in the same application or IDE, such as SQL Developer? Or do you need a solution that will run like a regular SQL statement anywhere? (The first scenario require some SQL\*Plus-like commands, the second scenario requires installing PL/SQL objects to extend SQL to be more dynamic.)

Comment: This query will be saved in a .sql file which will be called by a linux script. This linux script will pass the value of the `POS` or `PRE` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it works.

```
SQL> create table tb_a as select * from dept where deptno in (10, 20);  --> for POS

Table created.

SQL> create table tb_b as select * from dept where deptno in (30, 40);  --> for PRE

Table created.

SQL> select * from tb_a where '&&prod' = 'POS'
  2  union all
  3  select * from tb_b where '&&prod' = 'PRE';
Enter value for prod: POS

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS

SQL> undefine prod
SQL> /
Enter value for prod: PRE

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL>
```

Comment: the number of columns in the tables is different

Comment: UNION requires **number of columns** and their **datatypes** in both (actually, *all*) SELECT statements to be **equal**. Therefore, don't use `SELECT *` but list all columns involved, one-by-one.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function (or a procedure) which returns a record set of `SYS_REFCURSOR` type parameter after accepting one of your parameters (`POS`,`PRE`) no matter what structure has your tables(`tb_a` or `tb_b`) such as

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Get_tab_ab( i_prod VARCHAR2 ) RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
  v_recordset  SYS_REFCURSOR;                     
  v_sql        VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  v_sql := 'SELECT * FROM '||CASE 
                             WHEN i_prod = 'POS' THEN 
                                  'tb_a' 
                             WHEN i_prod = 'PRE' THEN 
                                  'tb_b' 
                              END;
  OPEN v_recordset FOR v_sql;
  RETURN v_recordset;
END;
/
```

and then call from SQL Developer's console like this

```sql
SQL> DECLARE
    res SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
   :res := Get_tab_ab('POS');
END;
/

SQL> PRINT res;
```

or you can use a common `ROWTYPE` variable because the structures of the tables(`tb_a` or `tb_b`) are identical considering you are combining them with a `UNION ALL` operator along with `FETCH..INTO` clause. This time you'll directly print out the desired columns without creating a stored object such as a function or procedure, just switching the value of the variable `v_prod`

```sql
DECLARE
  v_recordset  SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_rec        tb_a%ROWTYPE;
  v_sql        VARCHAR2(32767);
  v_prod       VARCHAR2(3) := 'POS';
BEGIN

  v_sql := 'SELECT * FROM '||CASE 
                             WHEN v_prod = 'POS' THEN 
                                  'tb_a' 
                             WHEN v_prod = 'PRE' THEN 
                                  'tb_b' 
                              END;
  OPEN v_recordset FOR v_sql;
  LOOP
     FETCH v_recordset INTO v_rec;
    EXIT WHEN v_recordset%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_rec.col1||' '||v_rec.col2||' '||v_rec.col3);
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE v_recordset;
  
END;
/
```

Comment: The number of columns in the tables is different and I am using Oracle SQL Developer.
The function call returned the following error:
`Error from line: 1 in command -
DECLARE
     res SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    :res := Get_tab_ab('POS');
END;
Error reporting -
ORA-06550: line 4, column 21:
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
ORA-06550: line 4, column 4:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 - "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause: Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:`

Comment: Then the first SELECT statement already would fail @Tom AL

Answer (score 0):

If the logic of choosing the table must be done in the SQL script, you need to pass in the PRE or POS to the script, use a bind variable to determine the table name, convert the bind variable into a substitution variable, and then select from the substitution variable. (It seems like there ought to be a simpler way to do this.)

```
--Pass in either "PRE" or "POS" to this script, and it will select from the appropriate table.


--AVoid the "old" and "new" lines when variables are substituted.
set verify off;

--Create a bind variable and a substitution variable.
variable table_name_bind varchar2(128);
column table_name_column new_value table_name_substitution_variable noprint

--Assign the bind variable based on the input argument.
begin
    if '&1' = 'POS' then
        :table_name_bind := 'tb_a';
    elsif '&1' = 'PRE' then
        :table_name_bind := 'tb_b';
    else
        raise_application_error(-20000, 'Unexpected input value &1');
    end if;
end;
/

--Convert the bind variable into the substitution variable through a SQL statement.
select :table_name_bind table_name_column from dual;

--Select from the substitution variable:
select * from &table_name_substitution_variable;

exit;
```

Comment: We really use SQL*Plus, Jon.
I need something like the pseudocode below:

`var = &1
-- if var = 'POS' then
SELECT * FROM TB_A

-- if var = 'PRE' then
SELECT * FROM TB_B`
Thanks

Comment: @TomAL See my updated answer.